Finite cover of Weyl group act on lie algebra
The following text is from "A guide to quantum groups".

The Weyl group $W$ of a complex simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ acts as a group of
reflections on the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{b}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. It is well known that
this action extends to an action of a finite covering $\tilde{W}$ of $W$ as a
group of Lie algebra automorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$, and hence to an action on the
universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ by Hopf algebra automorphisms

Are there reference for this? For example, what's the $\tilde{W}$ in $sl_n$ case?
